# Best answer contest: First quarter of 5778

Tags: discussion, status-completed, answer-contest

Have you seen (or written) a recent answer on Mi Yodeya that you thought was really great? Let's have a contest to help you tell everyone about it!

This contest has two phases: Nomination and Voting. It is currently in the **Voting** phase.

1. **Nomination** - ended December 25, 2017

   Post an answer to this Meta post containing a link to the Mi Yodeya answer you want to nominate. Answers created in **Tishrei - Kislev, 5778 (from September 21, 2017 through December 18, 2017)** are eligible.

   Please link to one answer in each entry. Nominate as many answers as you like in separate answers to this post.

   *When you see a great answer, don't wait; post a link to it here before you forget!*

   Please *do not* vote on any answers to this post during the Nomination phase.
2. **Voting** - December 25, 2017 - January 1, 2018

   The Voting phase has begun.

   Please vote on the answers to this post however you see fit. Upvote (or downvote, I guess) as many as you like.

[image: 300-point Bounty button]

The answer linked in the highest voted answer to this meta post will receive a bounty of 300 points after completion of the event on January 1, 2018. In case of a tie, the distinction will be shared, and the prize will be split.

---

<sup>Concept and words borrowed from [Movies.SE](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2558/rewards-for-the-best-answer-from-the-4th-quarter-of-2016).</sup>

Comment: Isaac, I'm please about the specific dates on the Gregorian calendar that you chose :-)

Comment: Protocol / clarity for these types of contests. Does it matter when the question was posted, or only that the answer should be within this timeframe? What about an answer posted before the timeframe but edited within the timeframe?

Comment: @DanF "Answers *created* in [timeframe] are eligible." I see no value in getting more complicated than that.

Comment: Isaac - StackExchange won't let me vote for my own nomination. Hmmm ... I don't think there's anything that you can do on your end to change that, but, it doesn't seem like a fair rule, here, esp. if I'm nominating someone else's question, no?

Comment: @DanF Chill, dude. Everyone who participates is a winner.

Comment: @danf every answer here has an implied first upvote from the poster, so no one is disadvantaged.

Comment: Locked to end voting

Answer (score 6):

[b a](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/1569/b-a)'s [answer](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/87312/11501) to [Was Psalm 29 derived from Canaanite sources?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/87217/11501) brings independent research and a clear fact base to disprove the hypothesis of the OP in a convincing way.

Answer (score 6):

[Double AA](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/759/double-aa)'s [answer](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/87311/11501) to [Sanhedrin/Makkot - One masechta?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/87196/11501) quotes from a wide gamut of sources (incl. Geniza material!) and reflects significant research work to answer the OP

Answer (score 4):

[Mauro Braunstein](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/85803/759)'s [answer](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/85803/759) to [How does one know the tune when praying in Hebrew?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/85776/759) provides background on various prayer tunes for many different communities and includes links to examples. Besides its wide scope, the answer puts musical ideas into words that are understandable even without hearing the music.

Answer (score 3):

[mbloch's](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/11501/mbloch) [answer](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/87374/5275) to [Why does congregational prayer require a chazan / shaliach tzibbur (cantor)?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/64553/5275) provides an excellent answer to the historical functions of the shaliach tzibbur using a variety of angles and links to different sources on this fascinating topic.

Answer (score 1):

[My](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/8775/mevaqesh) own [answer](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/85926/8775) to [Why is it that being embarrassed on one sin should atone for all](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/85920/why-is-it-that-being-embarrassed-on-one-sin-should-atone-for-all)? It brings dozens of examples for the linguistic phenomenon in question from many places in Hazal. In addition, it notes that the question depends on the accurate text of multiple Talmudic passages and brings almost a dozen relevant medieval manuscripts, and the views and versions of multiple Rishonim. It also provides context for the different possible versions, from yet more Hazalic passages. Finally, it cites a commentator who asks the exact question and answers it.

Answer (score 0):

[mevaqesh](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/8775/mevaqesh)'s [answer](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/85842/rosh-hashanah-as-a-day-of-friendliness/85846#85846) to [Rosh HaShanah as a Day of Friendliness](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/85842/rosh-hashanah-as-a-day-of-friendliness) brings just the right source to back up what  the OP was saying. What amazes me is that he knew just where to look, as he answered the question within the same day.

Answer (score 0):

[Alter](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/4736/alter)’s [answer](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/87682/) to [Are professor Daniel Boyarin's writings about the messiah supported in traditional Jewish sources?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/87678) To someone who knows the information, it may be an easier question to answer, but between just the sheer volume of information he brings to blast the professor’s claims and the manner in which he does it, this just blew me away.