# Best Answer Contest winners! First quarter of 5778

Tags: discussion, status-completed, answer-contest

Congratulations and *Yeyasher Kochachem* to the co-winners of the [Best Answer Contest for the first quarter of 5778](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4410/best-answer-contest-first-quarter-of-5778)!

Here are the original citations, both submitted by mbloch:

- [b a](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/1569/b-a)'s [answer](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/87312/11501) to [Was Psalm 29 derived from Canaanite sources?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/87217/11501) brings independent research and a clear fact base to disprove the hypothesis of the OP in a convincing way.
- [Double AA](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/759/double-aa)'s [answer](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/87311/11501) to [Sanhedrin/Makkot - One masechta?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/87196/11501) quotes from a wide gamut of sources (incl. Geniza material!) and reflects significant research work to answer the OP.

The winning entries will split the 300-point bounty prize evenly.

[Best answer contest: Second quarter of 5778](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4456/best-answer-contest-second-quarter-of-5778), covering Tevet through Adar, 5778 (from December 19, 2017 through March 16, 2018), is ***already underway***. If you see a new great answer, please enter it!